# React: re-define ref when component change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref

I have a mapping between index with component:

```
const mappingComponent = [
    {
        index: 0,
        component: Information,
    },
    {
        index: 1,
        component: Data,
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        component: UseCase,
    },
    {
        index: 3,
        component: Categorization,
    },
    // ...
];
```

Inside my Component:

```
const stepRef = useRef<StepRef>(null);

const renderUI = () => {
    const Component = mappingComponent.find((mc) => mc.index === step)?.component;
    if (!Component) return null;
    return (
        <Component
            ref={stepRef}
        />
    );
};
```

The interface:

```
export interface StepRef {
    onNext: () => void;
}
```

On each child component, I use `fowardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`:

```
useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
        onNext: () => {
           // TODO
        },
    }),
    [],
);
```

Step is a number state to decide which component is rendered

The proplem is when the step change, the `stepRef.current` become `null`.
How can I make the ref have values again?

Comment: Where does the `step` variable come from?

Comment: What is `ref.current`? I think we need a bit more detail, and a complete and coherent [mcve].